# OpenGL GL_POLYGON not printing correctly

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl

I am drawing a basic polygon with 5 sides that looks like a C shape almost.

```
(50,60) _____(70,60)
       |    /
       |   /
       |  /(60,40)
       |  \
       |   \
(50,20)|____\(70,20)
```

Pretty straightforward.

When I use

```
wcPt2D verts[5] = {{50,20}, {70,20}, {**60**,40}, {70,60}, {50,60}};
```

[image]

I get this. Expected. But when I change that center piece to

```
wcPt2D verts[5] = {{50,20}, {70,20}, {**51**,40}, {70,60}, {50,60}};
```

I get

[image]

Which is clearly not 1 unit from the left wall/9 units to the left of image 1, and it clearly drops the y value by approximately 10 units. Why is this?

```
void polygon (wcPt2D *verts)
{
GLint k;

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for (k = 0; k < 5; k++)
    {
        glVertex2f(verts [k].x,verts [k].y);
    }
glEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior of `GL_POLYGON` is only defined for convex polygons. Your polygon is concave, so the behavior of this function is undefined (and, as you've observed, it doesn't always work).

You will need to break your polygon up into one or more convex polygons for this to work correctly. In your case, one easy way of doing this would be to "cut" horizontally across the polygon:

```
(50,60) _____(70,60)
       |    /
       |   /
(50,40)|__/(60,40)
       |  \
       |   \
(50,20)|____\(70,20)
```